# How i can solve this limit?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How i can solve this limit? I Try substituting $x=r\cos\theta$ , $y=r\sin\theta$, but it has not worked.
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}{\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}}$$

Comment: $\lim_{t \to 0} \sin(t) / t = 1$.

Comment: This must be $1$ because you can change $x^2+y^2=z$ and you have $\frac{\sin z}{z}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use polar transformation: $x^2+y^2=r^2$ then the limit becomes 
$$
\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(r^2)}{r^2}=1
$$